# Replace emoticons in string with keywords

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Most emoticon replacement functions are stuctured as follows:

```
array(
  ':-)' => 'happy', ':)' => 'happy', ':D' => 'happy', ...
)
```

This, to me, seemed a bit redundant (especially while I don't need to make a distinction between 'happy', such as :-) and VERY happy, such as :-D. So I've come up with this:

```
$tweet = 'RT @MW_AAPL: Apple officially rich :-) LOLWUT #ipod :(';

function emoticons($tweet) {
  $emoticons = array(
    'HAPPY' => array(':-)', ':-D', ':D', '(-:', '(:'),
    'SAD'   => array(':-(', ':('),
    'WINK'  => array(';-)', ';)'),
    );

  foreach ($emoticons as $emotion) {
    foreach ($emotion as $pattern) {
      $tweet = str_replace($pattern, key($emoticons), $tweet);
    }
  }

  return $tweet;
}
```

The output should be:

```
RT @MW_AAPL: Apple officially rich HAPPY LOLWUT #ipod SAD
```

However, I don't know how to call the correct key from $emoticons. In my code, it seems to always replace any emoticon with keyword "HAPPY".

(1) If you see what's wrong with my code, then please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)
(2) I'm using str_replace here, while I see many other funciotns use preg_replace. What would be the advantage of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough, taking advantage of the fact that `str_replace` accepts arrays for any of its first two parameters:

```
foreach ($emoticons as $emot => $icons) {
    $tweet = str_replace($icons, $emot, $tweet);
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/ySvGL)**.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
foreach ($emoticons as $emotion) {
    foreach ($emotion as $pattern) {
      $tweet = str_replace($pattern, key($emoticons), $tweet);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
foreach ($emoticons as $key => $emotion) {
      $tweet = str_replace($emotion, $key, $tweet);
}
```